# Convert Bluetooth Sensor Data from NSData to int

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, gatt

We are reading values via Bluetooth (GATT) from a TI SensorTag 2 and need interpret the Barometric value which seems to be four byte value.

After trying a lot of options found here at stackoverflow and none of them worked I am hoping anyone could help?!

This is for example one of the options we tried: 
   int theInteger;
   [characteristic.value getBytes:&theInteger length:sizeof(theInteger)];

Ideas welcome!

Comment: Be more specific about why the options did not work. Show the results, input bytes and obtained values.

Comment: Running into the same problem.